# Multicollinearity between categorical and continuous predictors

Tags: multicollinearity

How can I check collinearity between categorical and continuous predictors (there are four predictors)?

Comment: You could use the generalized collinearity diagnostics suggested by [Fox J & Monette G (1992)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2290467?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: If you use R, I would recommend https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-2/topics/vif .